# Cant get strings from db throught php and java in android app

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I have mysql db and php script to get data from db.
I cant get array of strings in my android app, textview is empty no matter what I do. I checked my php and it is actually working so i guess i have some error in java code in android:

```
        bShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                        showUrl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        System.out.println(response.toString());
                        try {
                            JSONArray students = response.getJSONArray("demo");
                            for (int i = 0; i < students.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject student = students.getJSONObject(i);

                                String name = student.getString("name");
                                String lastname = student.getString("lastname");
                                String age = student.getString("age");

                                tvResult.append(name + " " + lastname + " " + age + " \n");
                            }
                            tvResult.setText("===\n");

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        System.out.append(error.getMessage());

                    }
                });
                requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and my php file:

```
    <?php

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
        include 'connection.php';
        showStudent();
    }

    function showStudent()
    {
        global $connect;

        $query = " Select * FROM demo; ";

        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
        $number_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        $temp_array  = array();

        if($number_of_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $temp_array[] = $row;
            }
        }

        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode(array("students"=>$temp_array));
        mysqli_close($connect);

    }

?>
```

I tried php an mysql with postman and my guess is that im missing the obvious in java.

Any help is welcomed.

Comment: you're looking for a `demo` key in your java code, but your php code generates `students`...

Answer (score 1):

Query:

```
$query = " Select * FROM demo ";
```

your php is generating an array called: `students`

```
 echo json_encode(array("students"=>$temp_array));
```

and you are trying to get an array called `demo`

```
   JSONArray students = response.getJSONArray("demo");
```

change to:

```
   JSONArray students = response.getJSONArray("students");
```